# How do I run a power analysis for a 2x2x2 ANOVA?

Tags: anova, mixed-model, statistical-power

I have a 2(between) x 2(within) x 2(within) design and would like to calculate the a-priori power needed to detect a three-way interaction using an ANOVA. I've read that this can't be done using power analysis software solutions and I'm completely lost on how best to proceed.

More specifically, my between subjects variable is my 2 experimental conditions and the 2 within subjects variables are (1) pre-/post-condition outcome measurement and (2) a measurement of the same outcome but of it's deviation upon presentation of a probe at the pre- and post- time points.

Happy to give more info if helpful. I'd be really grateful for any advice!

Comment: Simulation would be the best approach